# After waking from hibernation/suspend, screen displays noise pattern

Tags: upgrade, graphics, 20.04, suspend

This is how the screen of my Lenovo T410 appears when it wakes up from hibernation. Sometimes I see other noise patterns, but it never wakes up to the password unlock screen anymore. It doesn't react to any Fn, Ctrl, Alt key combination I've tried, and will only work normal again after a reboot. It also works if it's waking up from sleep (i.e. if I don't close the lid).

[image]

This started happening only after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04. It looks like a graphics driver issue.

Comment: worked only once for me. ctrl-click mouse, then enough of a screen to see that alt-f2, r, enter to get the screen back on reset. maybe I was dreaming. see Answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388688/when-i-suspend-ubuntu-20-04-with-running-gdm3-it-turns-to-black-screen-with-no

Comment: upgraded to 5.13.0-27-generic just using normal addate/upgrade. crtl+click worked 3 times in a row, though resuming this command took 10 seconds or so, but it seems to work.    i=1; while true; do i=$((i+1)); echo $i ; sleep 1; done

Comment: note this amd hp x360 ryzen 7 does not have a flashing power button on this suspend, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have hybrid graphics with an NVIDIA card on your system? If so, maybe try installing the NVIDIA graphics drivers. I had similar problems which were resolved upon installing the proprietary NVIDIA drivers. [Steps to install the driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/61433#61433)

This might not be the best solution, but it seemed to work for me.

Cheers!

Comment: I installed the Nvidia driver (version 340), rebooted, and the noise issue is gone! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Same issue on Lenovo laptop after a recent system update. This was not an issue before the recent system update.

The system has only AMD integrated GPU, so Nvidia drivers won't help. The HDMI connected screen works fine after unlock, so the noise appears only on the laptop's own monitor.

The issue is with a bug in the AMD GPU driver that ships with Linux kernel 5.13 through the Lenovo OEM kernels:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1783

Linux kernel version 5.14 fixes this issue but it's not yet updated to the official archives. If you manually install kernel version 5.14 it fixes the issue.

Related issue:
[Screen noise after resume from suspend or switch to tty (Ctrl+Alt+Fx)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1376973/screen-noise-after-resume-from-suspend-or-switch-to-tty-ctrlaltfx/1383115#1383115)

Comment: That's exactly what I need! I had the "noise" on Linux (Ubuntu) with AMD GPU (on Lenovo laptop). I used convienient script for upgrading kernel version ``wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh && sudo install ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh /usr/local/bin/ && sudo /usr/local/bin/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh –i`` And the "noise" is gone after reboot.