# Chromium screen refresh problem after wakeup from sleep

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, graphics, chromium

I have been using chromium and this laptop for more than 4 years and never faced this problem earlier. All service packs are up to date and current OS version is 20.04. Problem started happening around two months back on 18.04 and updating operating system did not help either.

After closing the lid of the laptop, when I start the laptop again, chromium fails to refresh the screen. All I get is grainy screen. Moving mouse just repaints area underneath, but switching tabs or switching to different application all together does not force refresh. Only for chromium, screen looks like [image at this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271407/after-waking-from-hibernation-suspend-screen-displays-noise-pattern). All other applications work normally.

Basically, after waking up the laptop, I have restart chromium. No other application is facing this problem. If screen saver kicks in and I log in again, I don't face this problem. Only after closing the laptop lid and only for chromium.

Upgrading to 20.04 from 18.04 did not help either.

lspci command reports graphics card as Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with chrome browser after suspend the computer on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1273399/problems-with-chrome-browser-after-suspend-the-computer-on-ubuntu-20-04) and [Chrome causing weird flickering since upgrade to 85.0.4183.83](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270689/chrome-causing-weird-flickering-since-upgrade-to-85-0-4183-83)

Comment: Yes it does. After setting the flags as indicated by Zato, I did not have any issues. Do you want me to close the question or want to put this as an answer for me to accept.

Comment: Please close it. Thank you!

Comment: @user3140225 I have voted to close the question, but not deleted it. People describe the same problem in different ways like I did. If I delete the question, they may no get to right answer as it did not show up in my search results.

Comment: Yes. Closing is more appropriate than deleting, exactly for the reasons you mention.