# Lenovo Thinkpad T14 screen glitches after resume from suspend Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: drivers, 20.04, suspend, thinkpad, amd-ryzen

[Screen glitch after suspend wakeup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FraQr.jpg)

Hi there,

I was hoping to find an answer here on this screen glitch problem after waking up with my Lenovo Thinkpad T14 with an AMD Ryzen PRO 4650U card. Since one week this [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FraQr.jpg) screen noise/glitch starts appearing and it now happens every time my laptop resumes from sleep. Only way is to restart.

Before I had already waking up problems but they've disappeared after I changed wake-up mode from Windows to Linux in the BIOS.

Version Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Kernel 5.13.0
Output of $ inxi

```
$ inxi
CPU: 6-Core AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650U with Radeon Graphics (-MT MCP-) 
speed/min/max: 1397/1400/2100 MHz Kernel: 5.13.0-21-generic x86_64 Up: 2m 
Mem: 1661.3/15218.2 MiB (10.9%) Storage: 476.94 GiB (29.5% used) Procs: 359 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 inxi: 3.0.38
```

I found the same issue here for the NVIDIA card [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1271407/after-waking-from-hibernation-suspend-screen-displays-noise-pattern/1375881#1375881) .

Any ideas how to proceed with an AMD card?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been fixed in Kernel version 5.14.

https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1783

Comment: Since I have the same problem: manually installing said Kernel version will fix it? I usually don't temper with the Kernel so I just want to be sure.

Comment: Yes, that worked for me. I installed the latest 5.15 kernel using this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~tuxinvader  Furthermore, because of my bios settings (secure boot enabled) I needed to sign the kernel. I found an excellent instruction at: https://gloveboxes.github.io/Ubuntu-for-Azure-Developers/docs/signing-kernel-for-secure-boot.html