# Screen noise after resume from suspend or switch to tty (Ctrl+Alt+Fx)

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, suspend, screen, noise

[ RESOLVED ] See answers and comments.

Since a recent kernel upgrade, my notebook screen shows a completely noisy image like an analog television without signal, whenever resuming from shutdown, or when switching to a virtual tty terminal (Ctrl+Alt+Fx). The noise is only on the LCD, not on the extended HDMI screen.

The problem does not show on other computers, so it must be hardware related. When rebooted using the previous kernel, the problem's gone.

My system:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Lenovo Thinkpad E14 Gen2 AMD
- Integrated AMD Radeon graphics
- 5.13.0-21-generic = problem (noise)
- 5.11.0-40-generic = no problem

I should also mention that I did a recent firmware upgrade on the SSD, which is fully encrypted by the way. At first, I thought that was the problem, so I rolled back the upgrade, but to no effect. I still doubt that could have been the trigger, though.

Anybody having the same problem?

Comment: I am the poster of this question. Just for the record: The issue seems resolved with the current kernel 5.13.0-30. I'd like to thank Antti Hukkanen and 83ingD33p for their helpful answers which gave me hope. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I was experiencing exactly the same thing on Lenovo L15 AMD flavor (integrated AMD Radeon).

Same thing that this issue started to appear very recently (few weeks ago) after system upgrades.

I am also running on an encrypted SSD but I haven't done any firmware upgrades. But this is not related to the GPU driver issue.

The real issue is with Linux kernel version 5.13 which ships with a buggy AMD GPU driver:
https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1783

This is fixed in Linux kernel version 5.14 which is not yet available in the official PPAs. But I tried manually installing the 5.14 kernel and the issue is gone, so it should fix when the next kernel update becomes available at the official repositories.

Comment: Just to reaffirm. Doing this worked for me for my Asus ROG Zephyrus 14. I was facing exactly same problem (although I did not test using another screen to converge on hardware issue). Manually updated to v5.15 and this seems to have worked.