# When I suspend Ubuntu 20.04 with running GDM3, it turns to black screen with no cursor and no mouse-pointer

Tags: screen, gdm

When I close my laptop's cover, it suspends. But when I open it, it is blackscreen with no cursor or mouse-pointer. I tried `sudo apt reinstall gdm3`, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold control and click to show the pointer when opening the screen, similar to when using a Linux VM in Windows or Mac.

I've used 3 PCs running Ubuntu 20.04, and they all have affected the black screen in this way when running GDM3. If I wait for longer, screensaver and I have the same issue but only when running GDM3. It seems to be a bug with 20.04, as I did not experience it in earlier versions.

It isn't a forever fix, but the control-click should locate your cursor and pointer.

Comment: you do not address the blank screen?

Comment: but  for one time only the ctrl-left click did work to get the some keyboard back then alt-F2 ,r , enter to reset the goofy screen. now it doesn't work. 'it is the ubuntu way' or 'the amd way'

Comment: If power cycling or suspending in the case of a VM does not work I would restore with a clean install on the server. That was the only thing I found that fixed the force suspend issue on 20.04

Comment: that might do it, I have two laptops, both AMD Ryzen. the one which cannot suspend was a Clonezilla image of the first one which can suspend. I did manage though to get hiberbate to work on the second one.